# How to load database at App Start up?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, startup

I'm developing an App that Loads database of Airports.
I put the database ".JSON" File in my Application in Xcode.
Everything's working well, except a Very long time to load the database.

I used this way to get an array from the JSON File.

```
-(void)readDataFromFile
{
    NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airports" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError * error;
    NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }


    self.airports = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];



    NSLog(@"%@",self.airports);



}
```

**MY QUESTION**

How can I move this time of wait when the application load?
In Small Words I need to load the database at the Start up !

Comment: Why are you loading and parsing a static JSON file on all the time? It would be far more efficient to provide a preloaded SQLite database file with your app. Then you don't need to parse the data every time and queries will be far more efficient and you don't need the whole database in memory.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks ! I thought about it ! can you please show me the Steps to do "by code" about how to get this preloaded Sqlite Db and an example of Query ?

Comment: That's far too broad of a question. I was simply pointing you in a better direction. Do some research on using SQLite. If you get stuck on something specific, post a new question about that specific issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I know how to use SQLite but don't know how to link the JSON db with SQlite, any help ?

Comment: @rmaddy if i convert the JSON File to Sqlite db, will it work ?

Comment: You need to do a one-time conversion of your JSON data to a SQLite database. Write a simple little throw-away app to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest time to do this is in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your app delegate class.

Comment: I need the database in the middle of the app ! How can i Load it in Appdelegate file in order to link it to the Tableview or other Viewcontrollers in the app ?

Comment: Well, there a various patterns to doing that. Could you rather not have this data in a Plist file? Would be much easier and quicker load time?

Comment: I can convert the .JSON to .Plist " No Problem for me "

Comment: That will be your easiest way - as you could access it where ever you need it. Good luck.

Comment: It's a Very large file with .Plist 89MB in JSON it was just 30MB ! and it's the same problem ! :( It's always slow ! I tested it also in my iPhone 6plus

Comment: At that size, there is no getting around it. JSON is better then. Look into moving it into Core Data. Again, will have access to it where ever you need. But you're not going to get away from the slow loading - thats a big file to read + display.

Comment: I would try to load it into Coredata ! Do you have a Code for that ? :D

Comment: @Tander How does using a plist instead of JSON help anything? If anything, that will be worse. Parsing XML is probably less efficient than parsing JSON.